# Pig installation in Cygwin

Tags: bash, hadoop, apache-pig

I have installed Hadoop 2.3.0 in windows successfully, but while trying with installing PIG using cygwin, i'm stuck with an error that says

```
pig -version
cygpath: cannot create short name of C:\pig\logs
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
```

and here is my bash variables

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.7.0_45
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export HADOOP_HOME=/cygdrive/c/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

export PIG_HOME=/cygdrive/c/pig
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
```

Can anyone help me why this error occurs?

Updated:
If i add HADOOP_CLASSPATH as below,

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(cygpath -pw $(hadoop classpath)):$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

then i'm getting an different error as

```
14/04/29 10:41:42 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the same IO problem. Did you made any progress ?

Comment: @fxm Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23577268/1282533 i have described the complete steps to install and make the PIG work in windows.